# Advanced ATX Power Supply Modifications

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, boost, atx

I know there are multiple tutorials and questions regarding converting an ATX power supply, new or old, to a benchtop power supply for projects. I'm fully aware of how to make the basic conversion to get 12V and 5V connections but I would like to take it a step further.

I have a relatively new 900W power supply which I got for very little money and would ultimately like to turn it into a variable high power supply. I plan on adding all of the extra circuitry to do what I want to do in an external housing and have the cables from the ATX power supply simply plug into my new box. The list of what I intend to do is as follows:

1. Use an active load balancing circuit to combine all 5 of the 12V rails into one 12V rail that can handle roughly 70A.

   - From what I understand most supplies use the same power source and multiple voltage regulator circuits to get the different rails.
2. Use a Boost Converter Circuit on the new combined line above to produce voltages up to say 50-60VDC
3. Use a Buck Converter on either a single 12V rail or the combined line to get voltages below 12VDC.

My question is, can I do the above as I intend? Are there issues with following an active voltage regulator load balancing circuit with an adjustable boost converter to step the voltage up and down? Same goes for the Buck Converter? Any alternative suggestions that would accomplish the same goal?

I am aware I could buy a decent variable power supply but I don't have the money currently for that and I thought this would be a fun project in power electronics. I intend to use the supply for some motor control development and testing, hence why I want to get much higher amperage than 1 12V rail can provide.

Comment: It is not uncommon for an ATX supply to generate all of the +12V in one place then split up into different rails by using some current limiting methods. That is to meet the 250W limit on a single output requirement of some common safety standards. Measuring the resistance between the different 12V rails may give you a hint. Because you may not need any load balancing circuit at all. Be aware that a buck or boost switching converter draws current in pulses. It would stress the outputs of the ATX supply with that not being part of original design expectations.

Comment: @rioraxe thanks for the comment. From what I have read even though they are the same source tying two different regulated buses in parallel might cause the regulators to fight or not share the load evenly, which is why I thought an active load balancing circuit was necessary. In reference to the Buck and Boost converters, is there a way I could reduce the stress on the original power supply? How do true variable switching mode power supplies handle it?

Comment: Measure the resistance between two separate +12V rails, if the resistance is close to 0 (e.g. <0.1ohm), that is a hint that both rails comes from one post regulated spot internally. They are likely to be split off from the same place with a current sense resistor each for the current limit function. Many application notes would show how to select an input capacitor for a corresponding input ripple. The input capacitor would scale up to be very big for a single phase 70A converter for moderate ripple current, so watch out for that. For 70A, you probably would not use single phase buck or boost.

Comment: I finally got around to measuring the resistance across the different rails and now I have another concern. I got 0 ohms across all connections, even between signal wires which is throwing me off. Any reason why everything would appear as though it's connected? I'll keep that in mind about the capacitor. What would you suggest about boost converter?

Comment: Ignore the part about every line being connected. It seems the capacitors had to charge because it says it's connected and then breaks connection. It appears that all 12V rails are tied together without any regulators separating them.

Comment: Try a search on "multiphase boost".